# list of dense as outputs

Tags: python, keras

I'm making a model whose output I want to be of dims (A,B).
So I'm making a list of denses (A elements, B outputs each) and I wanted my output to be (No_samples, A,B).
It is a list of A elements with (No_samples,B). The method of having one dense with output AxB does not help because for every row I want to softmax accross only that

I've attempted to use tf.concatenate, tf.reshape, but there is always either an error or the same undesirable output. My difficulty is that in order to proceed I have to do some really weird reshaping and I wish to avoid that by

```
for i in range(0, A):
    outputs.append(Dense(B, activation="softmax")(out))
```

And I've tried everything below (separately):

```
outputs = tf.stack(outputs)
outputs = Reshape(self.output_shape)(outputs)

outputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(outputs)
```

The expected outcome is that the output has shape of (A,?,B) instead of (?, A, B). Is there another method that I can have multiple denses in parralel with the above behaviour?

Comment: Because of softmax? You don't need to do anything at all. It will be in the last axis only.

Comment: If you want to `stack`, you must inform in which axis you want to stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example with A=3, B=1.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Concatenate, Dense, Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

def expand_dims(x):
    return K.expand_dims(x, axis=-2) #expand (None, 1) to (None, 1, 1)

x = Input((2,))
A = 3
B = 1
y = Lambda(expand_dims)(Dense(B, activation="softmax")(x))
for i in range(0, A-1):
    # Concatenate on the newly added dimension
    y = Concatenate(axis=-2)([y,Lambda(expand_dims)(Dense(B, activation="softmax")(x))])

model = Model(x, y)
print(model.predict(np.ones((4,2))).shape)
(4, 3, 1)  # Output shape is (No_samples, A,B)
```

Comment: It definetely works but it would be nice if you could offer some clarification. Like why are you expanding every layer and concatentating at the second to last axis

Comment: I added a couple of comments to the answer: the 'expand_dims' adds a new dimension to accommodate 'A' while the Concatenate is done on the newly added axis (A-1) times.